# Comparing time in php from mysql time is not giving right result

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql table for hours(field type `time`):

```
opened             closed
12:00:00           23:59:00
```

In php i need to check if the current time is between these two times.

FIrst i have converted php current server time into mysql time format

```
$cur_time = date('H:m A',$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
$cur_time = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i A',$cur_time);
$cur_time = $cur_time->format('H:i:s');
```

Then i have compared the times-

```
if($cur_time > $biz_hours['opened'] && $cur_time < $biz_hours['closed'])
```

Note: `$biz_hours` is the array to fetch data from mysql table.

Printing the `$cur_time` is displaying 09:12:00 just now. But if caluse returning false. Here is the live site url: http://dsbangladesh.com/takeout-banani/b/10 .  Please help me to find the problem.

Comment: I'd suggest doing the date / time checking in the sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison you are using is a simple string comparison. Your best bet is to convert your data into timestamps first.  Something like this:

```
$curTime = time();
$openTime = strtotime($biz_hours['opened']);
$closeTime = strtotime($biz_hours['closed']);

if($curTime > $openTime && $curTime < $closeTime)
{ ....
```

I've used `time` to get the current server time instead of the method you used.  I've also used `strtotime` to convert the mysql time field into a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (time() > strtotime($biz_hours['opened']) && time() < strtotime($biz_hours['closed']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $biz_o = new DateTime(date('H:i:s',strtotime($biz_hours['opened'])));
   $biz_c = new DateTime(date('H:i:s',strtotime($biz_hours['closed'])));
   $now = new DateTime(date('H:i:s'),strtotime($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']));
   if($now > $biz_o && $now < $biz_c){
       //You got me
   }
```